# Dynamic drop down updates based another drop down

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three drop down . category,Gender, Division . I can select any combination or single one

```
Category                  Gender         Division
Athletic                  Men              AP
Baseball                  Women             AR
```

Would like to update the column

```
Description
Atheltic-Men-AP (or)
Men(or)
AP(or)
Atheltic-AP(or)
Men-AP`
```

update table_name set ?

Present I am using this code

```
                 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.comboBoxCategory.Text))
                    decriptionGroup = this.comboBoxCategory.Text + " ";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.comboBoxDept.Text))
                    decriptionGroup += this.comboBoxDept.Text + " ";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.comboBoxDivision.Text))
                    decriptionGroup += this.comboBoxDivision.Text;    


UPDATE  table_Name  SET  Category_Desc ='" + decriptionGroup + @"'  

SELECT  Category_Desc AS [Description]  FROM table_Name
```

From this code I need to select category with out category it is polulating error

Comment: We need a bit more info on this. Can you show any code you have with current outcome and desired outcome.

Comment: if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.comboBoxCategory.Text))
                    decriptionGroup = this.comboBoxCategory.Text + " ";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.comboBoxDept.Text))
                    decriptionGroup += this.comboBoxDept.Text + " ";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.comboBoxDivision.Text))
                    decriptionGroup += this.comboBoxDivision.Text;

Comment: Whoa @sravas .. Kindly hit `edit` on your **O**riginal **P**ost -- Paste the code into it, and format it so we can read it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
         IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TempDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
   WHERE COLUMN_NAME = ''category_desc'' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '#Doors_2%'')
                     ALTER TABLE #Doors_2 ADD category_desc NVARCHAR(50) 

  UPDATE  table_Name  SET  Category_Desc ='" +  decriptionGroup + @"'  
                      ;WITH CLSDOORS2 AS
                       (
                       SELECT Style_Color, category_desc AS [Description], 
                  Store_ID, Cluster_Index, Total_Avg FROM #Cluster_Vlm_Doors_2
                       )
                       SELECT * FROM CLSDOORS2 '
```